# XCode 6.3 immediately raises SIGABRT on thrown Objective-C++ exceptions

Tags: objective-c, xcode6

Consider the following objective-C++ code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    try
    {
        throw std::logic_error("error message");
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s", ex.what());
    }
    return YES;
}
```

In XCode 6.2 it is working as expected ("error message" is logged). However since we upgraded to 6.3, the throwing line (`throw std::logic_error...`) raises `SIGABRT` (the stack trace only contains `_cxa_throw` and `_pthread_kill` beyond `applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`) and crashes the application.

This only happens in our application - when I copy the exact same code to a new project everything works well, even with identical compiler flags.

I've tried specifying `-fexceptions` and  `-fnon-call-exceptions` to no avail (same behavior).

**Update**
It seems this only happens on 32-bit simulators (it works on actual devices and 64-bit simulators).

**Update 2**
We narrowed it down to the [UserVoice iOS SDK](http://github.com/uservoice/uservoice-ios-SDK). The behavior is clearly displayed in a new vanilla project simply by linking against it (make sure you call some method so that linkage takes place). We haven't investigated what exactly in that library causes it yet, and we also have some internal libraries that provoke the same behavior (but they should be irrelevant to anyone outside Microsoft).

Comment: Same for debug vs. release?   Can you look the compiler's output to see if it matches between 6.2 and 6.3?  That might at least indicate if it's runtime and not compiler.

Comment: Also add a catch(...) to see if you're catching *something*

Comment: @KirkSpaziani same thing in both debug and release. The compiler output simply says *libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::logic_error: error message* (obviously this line is not present in 6.2 where the exception is properly caught). Adding `catch (...)` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks/cocoapods? e.g. crash handlers? It's just that the lack of detail about what's different between your app and a plain old vanilla app is vast, and you've not really given any hints

Comment: try using an objective-C++ `@catch`, according to the docs that should work better as it can (in the latest version at least) catch C++ exceptions

Comment: @Petesh we're actually using a crash handler, that's a very good hunch I'll check when I'm in the office. Of course the difference between our app and the vanilla app is vast, this is exactly the reason why the issue is so hard to debug. If you think there's anything else I should add (besides dependent frameworks which I will when I get to the office) please let me know\.

Comment: @Mgetz using `@try`/`@catch(...)` results in the same behavior I'm afraid

Comment: @Petesh Sadly disabling the crash handler doesn't work. As for other dependencies, we use some standard and internal libs for authentication, networking, serialization, and telemetry. Nothing in particular stands out, but I guess we'll start a binary search for the culprit. Also see the update in the question - seems like we're only getting hit in 32-bit simulators.

Comment: Same thing happening for me. It seems [Apple changed something related to C++ exceptions in Xcode 6.3](https://twitter.com/depth42/status/586548205753602048) but didn't bother documenting it in the release notes.

Comment: This is especially frustrating as the only iPad 64bit simulator is the iPad Air, and its retina resolution makes it so slow it's unusable.

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis we narrowed it down to the UserVoice iOS SDK: https://github.com/uservoice/uservoice-ios-sdk. If you're using it, you'll get this behavior for sure (we actually have some more internal libraries that provoke this behavior, but they are irrelevant to anyone outside MS).

Comment: @OhadSchneider It's one of our internal lib which is causing it too, no way we can function without it sadly :(. I guess the only option here is to file a Radar and wait...

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis were you able to isolate what exactly in that lib caused this behavior? In the UserVoice SDK it has to be some global initializer (as it happens before any UserVoice code is called), maybe your internal lib is doing something similar...

Comment: @OhadSchneider I was not able to isolate a source for the bug; and I'm not able to replicate it with a new project linking UserVoice... Could you share your crashing minimal project please ?

Comment: Another SO question on the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646999/try-catch-doesnt-catch-exception and a thread in the dev forums: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/267548?tstart=0 . No much more info in these though.

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis I don't have access to my Mac right now but basically create a new project in XCode, link the latest UserVoice lib (https://github.com/uservoice/uservoice-ios-sdk/releases/tag/3.2.3) add the snippet in my question and call something from the SDK (e.g. init some UserVoice object).

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the 64 bit simulators when running 32 bit binaries. I ran into this issue as well and only once I enabled 64 bit builds did exceptions catch correctly.

Comment: The question is, what exactly triggers this bug and can we work around it (our build is not ready for 64 bit yet)? There is something in the libraries I mentioned that provokes it....

Comment: Did you ever find a fix? I'm getting the same problem when using a few different 3rd party libraries...

Comment: @luna_ other than not using 32-bit binaries in the 64-bit simulators, I'm afradi not. Here's the latest word from who appears to be an Apple dev in their forums: *The problem should be fixed in the next beta release of Xcode 6.4. In the meantime, you might be able to avoid the problem by rebuilding all of your object files with the latest tools. Some of the reports that we've looked at show that the problem is exposed when using static libraries or other objects that were generated with older tools.*

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, is it just a simulator problem? I don't have any 32-bit devices to try on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this issue was an [XCode bug](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/267548?start=25&tstart=0) (linker specifically). It was reportedly fixed in XCode 6.4b3. I'm using 6.4 (6E35b) and indeed it seems  to have been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I've found 6.3 to be filled with serious bugs. Upgrading to 6.3.2 seemed to fixed all of my problems. Give that a shot.

Comment: I just tested 6.3.2 and I'm afraid the issue is not resolved. As far as I could tell from the apple developer forums thread (https://devforums.apple.com/thread/267548?tstart=0) it will only be resolved in 6.4.