# @try/@catch doesn't catch exception

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, xctest

After upgrading Xcode from 6.0 to 6.3, I noticed my automated tests started failing.

```
2015-04-14 18:56:50.625 xctest[48304:517820] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'foo', reason: 'bar'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0084a746 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x004d3a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0084a66d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
    3   TestTests                           0x03e6dbdc -[TestTest test] + 810
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0072b84d __invoking___ + 29
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x0072b6f8 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 360
    6   XCTest                              0x20108975 -[XCTestCase invokeTest] + 320
    7   XCTest                              0x20108baa -[XCTestCase performTest:] + 175
    8   XCTest                              0x20114122 -[XCTest run] + 314
    9   XCTest                              0x20107598 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 406
    10  XCTest                              0x20114122 -[XCTest run] + 314
    11  XCTest                              0x20107598 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 406
    12  XCTest                              0x20114122 -[XCTest run] + 314
    13  XCTest                              0x20107598 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 406
    14  XCTest                              0x20114122 -[XCTest run] + 314
    15  XCTest                              0x20103df2 __25-[XCTestDriver _runSuite]_block_invoke + 61
    16  XCTest                              0x20110c42 -[XCTestObservationCenter _observeTestExecutionForBlock:] + 184
    17  XCTest                              0x20103d16 -[XCTestDriver _runSuite] + 285
    18  XCTest                              0x20104961 -[XCTestDriver _checkForTestManager] + 272
    19  XCTest                              0x20104c79 -[XCTestDriver runTestSuite:completionHandler:] + 376
    20  XCTest                              0x2011772c +[XCTestProbe runTests:] + 216
    21  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x004e967e +[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    22  xctest                              0x0000823a xctest + 4666
    23  xctest                              0x000084b0 xctest + 5296
    24  xctest                              0x00008591 xctest + 5521
    25  xctest                              0x00007e3d xctest + 3645
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x019d4ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

After further investigation it appears exceptions are now uncatchable. Both these snippets would cause this error.

```
XCTAssertThrows([NSException raise:@"foo" format:@"bar"]);
```

and

```
@try {
    [NSException raise:@"foo" format:@"bar"];
}
@catch (NSException *ex) {
    NSLog(@"caught");
}
```

After a VCS force clean sync and rebuild everything looked fine, but then the same failure started in a couple of builds time. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You are not alone. But it's also not affecting everyone. Check [this thread in the developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/267548?tstart=0) for more information.

Comment: Information on the forums strongly suggests that it is related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/21150223/476716

Comment: I don't think silencing the warning will solve the this issue though.

Comment: Unclear whether it silences it or actually disables the feature, but either way it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Looks like the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609675/xcode-6-3-immediately-raises-sigabrt-on-thrown-objective-c-exceptions?noredirect=1#comment47540799_29609675

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the developer forums, this appears to be a bug or oversight in the developer tools that introduced an incompatibility with binaries built with older versions of the tools.

Should be fixed in Xcode 6.4

Comment: I have the same issue. But I want to catch an NSAssert I have in my code with @try-catch, but it doesn't work. I'm using Xcode 6.4 (6E35b). Any solutions to this?

Comment: Saw the same issue with 6E35b. It turned out that I had ldflags `-Wl,-no_compact_unwind` set, and this broke exception handling.